# Poincaré' lemma and EM potential $A^{\mu}$

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, standard-model, magnetic-monopoles

My lecturer said that given the sourceless Maxwell's equations $$ \partial_{\mu}\, ^ *F^{\mu\nu} = 0 $$,

we can find a solution $$ F^{\mu\nu}  = \partial_{\mu}A_{\nu} - \partial_{\nu}A_{\mu},$$

that only exists **locally**.

The fact that there always is a $A_{\nu}$ that can locally give $ F^{\mu\nu}$ is a consequence of Poincaré's lemma, and extending it to a *global* solution would introduce/require magnetic monopoles.

I tried to read up on the Poincore lemma but it's all maths and I was hoping for a physical explanation. Does it make sense that $A_{\nu}$ is local? How do mangetic monopoles enter the picture?

Comment: What do you mean *"Does it make sense that $A$ is local?"*? In electromagnetism, we *define* $A$ to be the potential of $F$ such that $F = \mathrm{d}A$. This definition rests on the Poincare lemma, you simply *can't* define the gauge field from given $F$ without it, so the *very definition* of $A$ is already local. (This is generally so for gauge theories, btw - the gauge field is always only defined *locally* on spacetime)

Comment: For magnetic monopoles, you might interested in [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/166967/50583)

Comment: It's the first time that I come across local stuff so I'm not used to it. Why are gauge field defined locally and not globally?

Comment: Perhaps also have a look at [What is the basis of gauge theory?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/126978/50583)

Comment: Comment to the question (v2): The equation $F_{\mu\nu}=\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}-\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}$ also holds in the presence of electric sources. No need to go to source-free Maxwell equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all some clarifications to make sure we are on the same page. The phrase "$A_\nu$ is local" is slightly misleading as it implies that A is only defined in some (small) neighborhood of the total manifold/space. This is not true. A is defined everywhere on the manifold. The correct expression is that "the theory is invariant under a local symmetry" ie that transformations of the form
$$A_\nu(x)\rightarrow A_\nu(x)+L(x)$$
do not change the physics. The above are known as *local/gauge* transformations and they are distinctly different from *global* transformations in which the function does not depend on the position, ie:
$$A_\nu(x)\rightarrow A_\nu(x)+L$$

Now the statement about the Maxwell's equation mentioned, is that we can find a solution to it at any small neighborhood of the manifold, but when we try to patch together solutions in nearby neighborhoods to find a solution that will satisfy the equation *everywhere*, then this is impossible (for manifolds that have "holes").

The basic (physical) reason behind this is that for manifolds with no holes a field of the form $A=$constant is not physical and we can do a gauge transformation of the type described above to bring it to the form $A=0$ everywhere. However, for manifolds with holes (an example would be the circle) a field that is constant everywhere is physical, it cannot be gauged away and has observable consequences. This is another manifestation of the [Aharonov–Bohm effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharonov%E2%80%93Bohm_effect).

So in the example above, if the constant magnetic field along the circle is physical then what creates it? We can think of its source as an electric current flowing through a long wire passing through the center of the circle and being perpendicular to the plane of the circle, or equivalently we can think about it as having placed a magnetic monopole at the center of the circle. This simple example hopefully demonstrates why magnetic monopoles are needed to be introduced to justify global solutions of Maxwell's equaitons on a space with non-trivial topology (ie with holes).