# Is the Dirac string continuous?

Tags: classical-electrodynamics, dirac-string

Is the [Dirac string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_string) continuous? Suppose I have a point magnetic charge. Do the necessary singularities of the vector potential lie on a continuous curve in 3D space?

Comment: The vector potential (as a globally defined gauge field) is only singular at the point of the magnetic charge. It's a *local coordinate representation* of it that develops singularities along the Dirac string, but the actual vector potential does not (that's the reason why the string has to be unobservable - it's a coordinate artifact, not an actual object of the theory), see [this answer of mine](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/167160/50583).