Condition for invariance of the lagrangian density of a massive vector field
In the lecture we were given the lagrangian for this case, which is:
$\mathcal{L}=-\frac{1}{4}F^{\mu\nu}(x)F_{\mu\nu}(x) + \frac{m^2}{2}A_\mu (x) A^\mu(x)$
We then considered a transformation of the form $A^\mu(x)\rightarrow A^\mu(x) -\partial^\mu f(x)$,
where $f(x)$ is an arbitrary smooth function
We were told that the invariance occurs when we consider Lorentz gauge and also that $\Box f(x)=0$.
Assuming that $F^{\mu\nu}(x)F_{\mu\nu}(x)$ is invariant under this transformation, something which I believe can be shown by inserting the transformation, for the mass term one would have:
$$\frac{m^2}{2}(A_\mu(x) -\partial_\mu f(x))(A^\mu(x) -\partial^\mu f(x))=$$
$$\frac{m^2}{2}(A_\mu A^\mu - A_\mu \partial^\mu f -\partial_\mu f A^\mu + \partial_\mu f \partial^\mu f)=$$
$$\frac{m^2}{2}(A_\mu A^\mu - A_\mu \partial^\mu f -(\partial_\mu f) A^\mu - f(\partial_\mu A^\mu) + (\partial_\mu f)\partial^\mu f + f\Box f )$$
The first term $A_\mu A^\mu$ is the mass term of the original lagrangian.
The third term $f(\partial_\mu A^\mu)$ contains the lorentz gauge, so it vanishes.
The last term $f\Box f =0$ because we are given the condition that $\Box f=0$.
But there are 2 problem here, from what I can tell:

The terms $2A_\mu\partial^\mu f$ is not zero and it should be if we want the lagrangian to be invariant.

The claim was made that $f\Box f =0$ but we were told that, $f(x)$ is an arbitrary smooth function And we know that: A smooth function is a function that has continuous derivatives of all orders. This property ensures that the function behaves nicely and can be differentiated repeatedly without encountering any abrupt changes or discontinuities


So, am I misunderstanding something or there's a mistake somewhere?

I'm not sure what this question is trying to do: The theory of the massive vector field is not a gauge theory, and I don't know what it means to "consider Lorentz gauge" in this context. See this question and my answer to it for a similar confusion about the massive vector field.


Gauge invariance occurs at the level of the action, not the Lagrangian. In the action, you can integrate by parts
$$
S = \int d^4 x B^\mu \partial_\mu C= - \int d^4 x C\partial_\mu B^\mu + {\rm boundary\ term}
$$
where $B^\mu$ and $C$ are a vector and scalar valued function respectively, and where the boundary term is $\int d^4 x \partial_\mu \left(C B^\mu\right)$, which can be converted to a boundary integral over the boundary of the spacetime volume integrated over in $S$ using Stoke's theorem, and which we typically drop assuming the fields die off at asymptotically spatial infinity, and that the initial and final configuration on the field on the initial and final time slices aren't varied. When you account for integration by parts, then you see that $A^\mu \partial_\mu f$ is equivalent to $-f \partial_\mu A^\mu$, in the sense that they will lead to the same action. And, $\partial_\mu A^\mu=0$ by assumption.

You are right that $\square f = 0$ is a stronger condition than the condition that $f$ is a smooth function. However, $\square{f}=0$ when you assumed when you said "We were told that the invariance occurs when we consider Lorentz gauge and also that $\square f = 0$." So you are allowed to use this stronger condition.



But does it make sense to consider chain derivatives? How can I know whether that is correct or not?

while the argument you put forwards eliminates the $A^\mu\partial_\mu f$, you still have to consider $(\partial_\mu f)(\partial^\mu f)$

@imbAF If you do another integration by parts that term is proportional to $\square f$.

I did that, but I also have a term of the form $f\partial f$ with boundaries $\pm \infty$. And this term must be zero. And the only argument I can give is that $f(x)$ goes to zero in that case. But I find this strange, cuz it would have been mentioned as a 3rd condition

Typically one also assumes $f$ dies off at spatial infinity. At a very basic level, this is just part of the usual assumption that you can drop boundary terms when you integrate by parts. A more sophisticated justification is that gauge transformations shouldn't change the asymptotic behavior of the field at infinity; that case corresponds to a global symmetry (see, eg, https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/326894/gauge-transformations-at-infinity)

I think you could ask a good follow up question about why gauge transformations should die off at infinity, but in terms of this question, that fact is used to throw away the boundary terms involving $f$.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
