# How does the lagrangian for a Klein-Gordon field changes?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, klein-gordon-equation

For K-G field, the lagrangian density

$$L=\frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu\phi\partial^\mu\phi-\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2$$

In ryder quantum field theory book i saw that in next step he writes

$$L=-\frac{1}{2}\phi(\partial_\mu\partial^\mu+m^2)\phi$$

My question is how did we got to second step from first,where did the minus sign came from and how did he pulled out a phi from the derivative in first step?

Comment: Didn't he just integrate the term by parts and dropped the surface term?

Comment: Can you please show it?

Comment: As @RaduMoga said, this is just the previous Lagrangian minus $\partial_\mu(\phi\partial^\mu\phi)$ (it's a good exercise to check this). Subtracting a total derivative doesn't change the action, or the Euler–Lagrange equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write $\partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi=\partial_\mu(\phi \partial^\mu \phi)-\phi\partial_\mu \partial^\mu \phi$ by the product rule for differentiation. The term $\partial_\mu(\phi \partial^\mu \phi)$ is a surface term that vanishes when the Langrangian density is integrated over spacetime (under certain assumptions such as the fields decaying fast enough at infinity). This essentially means we can make the replacement $\partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi \rightarrow -\phi\partial_\mu \partial^\mu \phi$ in the Lagrangian density.

Comment: Can you please say why is total derivative term the surface term?

Comment: That is what it is meant by surface terms in general. See also this post https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/370185/what-is-the-surface-term