# Compactification of space in Hamiltonian formulation of Yang-Mills theory

Tags: gauge-theory, yang-mills, compactification

I am reading David Tong's lecture notes on [Gauge Theory](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/gaugetheory.html) where he talks about Hilbert space interpretation of Yang-Mills theories in Section 2.2 of Chapter 2. When discussing the gauge dependence of the Chern-Simons functional $W[\textbf{A}]$, he assumes that the gauge transformation $\Omega(\textbf{x})\rightarrow 1$ as $|\textbf{x}|\rightarrow \infty$. [Previously, in the same section, he says all gauge transformations which are of the form $\Omega(\textbf{x})\rightarrow \text{constant} \ne 1$ as $|\textbf{x}|\rightarrow \infty$ can be generated by a *constant* gauge transformation (physical symmetries) of the above.] He goes on to say that, since we then *can* compactify $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $S^3$, such $\Omega(\textbf{x}):S^3 \rightarrow SU(2)$ are classified according to their homotopy classes in $\pi_3(SU(2))=\mathbb{Z}$. If they belong to class $n=0$, they are *small* gauge transformations, and if they belong to class $n\ne0$, they are *large* gauge transformations. [I guess this is similar to the classification of gauge transformations of the $U(1)$-bundle on $S^1$ according to their homotopy classes in $\pi_1(U(1))=\mathbb{Z}$. I mean large gauge transformations as described in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/314384/what-defines-a-large-gauge-transformation-really?noredirect=1&lq=1), or in Wikipedia.] In fact, the class corresponding to such $\Omega(\textbf{x})$ is given by

$$
n(\Omega)=\frac{1}{24\pi^2}\int_{S^3}d^3x\ \epsilon^{ijk}\text{tr}(\Omega^{-1}\partial_i \Omega \Omega^{-1}\partial_j \Omega \Omega^{-1}\partial_k \Omega) \in \mathbb{Z}.
$$

Now my question(s): why do we restrict ourselves to those gauge transformations which become constant at infinity? What about the gauge transformations which do not become constant at infinity? Since we then *can't* compactify the space, how do we classify these gauge transformations? What happens to the above integral for such gauge transformations? Is it still an integer?

Comment: I have the same question as yours. For example for constant magnetic field along z direction in xy palne , we may either choose A=B(-y,0,0) or B(0,x,0) , with gauge transformation Ω=exp^{ixy}, which is not constant at infinity. Do you have any idea now？

Comment: Probably this helps? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/314384/214661